# How to simultaneously select multiple fields to generate a constructor in Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea

When I want to generate a constructor, I can only choose one field at the same time. I searched online for keys for multiple selection and somebody answered that it's `Ctrl` & `Shift`. But when I press these two keys the only result is that my input method changes.

[image: IntelliJ IDEA Screenshot]

Comment: Try either Ctrl-click or Shift-click instead of Ctrl-Shift.

Comment: All right.. It works when I just click one key, but the way it works isn't like what I imagined(/"≡ _ ≡)/ anyway，thanks a lot!

Comment: @Pang, post it as an anwer, please

Answer (score 5):

The shortcut is Shift+Down_Arrow.

Answer (score 2):

The trick is, use this command ;

`Shift` + ⬇️

Answer (score 1):

shift + down arrow doesn't seem to work .ctrl + left_click works perfectly!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).